Trouble connecting to localhost after deploying Emuhub project with Docker
I've been trying to deploy the Emuhub project from GitHub (https://github.com/mohamed-helmy/emuhub?tab=readme-ov-file) on my localhost. I ran the container in the background using the command docker run -p 6080:6080 emuhub. However, I've encountered an issue where I can't connect to localhost, and the container logs show the following messages:
/bin/bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = "en_US",
        LC_ALL = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").

New '68490b3b470b:1 (emuhub)' desktop at :1 on machine 68490b3b470b

Starting applications specified in /etc/X11/Xvnc-session
Log file is /home/emuhub/.vnc/68490b3b470b:1.log

Use xtigervncviewer -SecurityTypes VncAuth -passwd /tmp/passwd :1 to connect to the VNC server.

bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
/bin/bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
Warning: could not find self.pem
Using installed websockify at /usr/local/bin/websockify
Starting webserver and WebSockets proxy on port --vnc
Usage: 
    websockify [options] [source_addr:]source_port [target_addr:target_port]
    websockify [options] --token-plugin=CLASS [source_addr:]source_port
    websockify [options] --unix-target=FILE [source_addr:]source_port
    websockify [options] [source_addr:]source_port -- WRAP_COMMAND_LINE

websockify: error: no such option: --vnc
Failed to start WebSockets proxy

The output continues with warnings and errors related to locale settings and websockify. I have tried various container running methods without success.
Could someone please help me troubleshoot and resolve this issue?

Just the error log isn't usually enough to debug things; can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  The number of different things in this output surprises me, can you restructure your application to have only one process in a container?  You say you can't connect "to localhost" but in Docker each container is separately its own localhost, where are you trying to connect to and from where?

try to run the docker container and path environment and volumes
like this
docker run -d \
  --name emulator \
  --privileged \
  -e VNCPASS=admin \
  -e emuhubPASS=admin \
  -e LISTENPORT=8000 \
  -p 8000:8000 \
  -v ./apk-demo:/home/emuhub/apk \
  --log-driver=json-file \
  --log-opt max-size=20m \
  --log-opt max-file=10 \
  emuhub

Volume Mappings:

-v /path/to/apk-demo:/home/emuhub/apk: This mounts the host directory /path/to/apk-demo to /home/emuhub/apk in the container.

Environment Variables:

-e VNCPASS=admin: Sets the VNC password to admin.

-e emuhubPASS=admin: Sets the EmuHub password to admin.

-e LISTENPORT=8000: Sets the port on which the application listens to 8000.


Logging Options:

--log-driver=json-file: Uses the json-file logging driver.

--log-opt max-size=20m: Limits the maximum size of the log file to 20MB.

--log-opt max-file=10: Keeps up to 10 log files.



Unfortunately it didn't work out again. The logs show the following errors. But I am absolutely sure that I have access to KVM. Here are the errors I got:
/bin/bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
chown: cannot access '/dev/kvm': No such file or directory
/bin/bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
/usr/local/bin/start-vnc.sh: line 17: /tmp/passwd: Permission denied
/bin/bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
/usr/local/bin/start-vnc.sh: line 17: /tmp/passwd: Permission denied

try to Verify KVM Access:
Even though you're sure you have access to KVM, it's a good idea to double-check. You can verify access by running:
kvm-ok
if ok ensure you add --privileged flag to give it extended privileges. this is especially important for accessing /dev/kvm
finally, try to remove the old container
